# Draw path only if condition is met

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, arrays

I am using TikZ and would like to draw a path from one node to another if a condition is met. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\hsep{5cm}
\def\ilsize{6}
\def\hlsize{6}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle, draw]
\tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron]
\tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron]

\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\ilsize}
    \node[input neuron] (In-\name) at (0.0cm,-\y cm) {};

\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\hlsize}
    \node[hidden neuron] (H0-\name) at (1.5cm+\hsep,-\y cm) {};
    
\def\array{{1,0,1,1,1,1}}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\ilsize}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,\hlsize}
        {
        %\ifnum\array[\i]=1
            \path (In-\i) edge (H0-\j);
        %\fi
        }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

However, the document does not compile if I use the if-condition

```
\ifnum\array[\i]=1
    \path (In-\i) edge (H0-\j);
\fi
```

Does someone see what I do wrong here?

Comment: Your code is not compilable. `! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> {l.33 }`

Comment: @AndréC I know :) I mentioned it in my question. This is why I asked for help.

Comment: Since you edited your question, it's clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the array does not contain integers but `ifnum` requires an integer.

You can use `pgfmathparse` to parse the entry from the array and `pgfmathresult` in the `ifnum` statement. Also you need to use `i-1` otherwise the last array index is out of bounds, because arrays are indexed starting with `0`.

```
\def\array{{1,0,1,1,1,1}}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\ilsize}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,\hlsize}
        {
        \pgfmathparse{\array[\i-1]}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \path (In-\i) edge (H0-\j);
        \fi
        }
```

Since `i` is a simple incremental counter, you could also use the `count` option of the `foreach` command and write the array directly in `foreach` statement. You would also not have any problems with indices of arrays and the maximum number of `i` would be determined by the length of the array instead of `ilsize`.

```
%\def\array{{1,0,1,1,1,1}}
\foreach [count = \i] \a in {1,0,1,1,1,1}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,\hlsize}
        {
        \ifnum\a=1
            \path (In-\i) edge (H0-\j);
        \fi
        }
```

Both solutions yield the same result:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, the first approach using `pgfmathparse` and `pgfmathresult` still uses your original definition of `array`.

Comment: The comment above related to a follow-up question that was posted as a comment which was later deleted.